# What does "assume hypothesis is true" really mean for proofs?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can I get clarification on why we assume the hypothesis is true for proof questions? Especially when the question starts with, $\forall x \epsilon \Bbb R$?

I just don't know why we can assume that part of a statement is true. And then if the conclusion happens to be true the whole statement is true.

My TA told me it's because we don't have to even consider if the hypothesis is false, because false implies true is always true? Can someone explain what that means? I know it might have to do something with the truth tables but..

Comment: wait what? Can you give context? I've never heard of this. Perhaps I misunderstand

Comment: A statement such as $\forall x\in A, P$ can be seen as shorthand for $\forall x,(P\lor\neg x\in A)$. So the only sensible case to study is the one where $x\in A$ is true.

Comment: So for example a question can say if a|b and a|c, then a|bc. And the process of proving it is apparently assuming a|b and a|c is true.. with no actual explanation needed

Comment: @SaucyO'Path So it's because if the hypothesis is false, the statement is automatically.. true?